# Findstr in windows bat

Tags: batch-file

I use the following command

```
  netstat -ano -p tcp | findstr  "18812"
```

and got result like this:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18812          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3116
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3099         127.0.0.1:18812        ESTABLISHED     5112
  TCP    127.0.0.1:18812        127.0.0.1:3099         ESTABLISHED     3116
```

But the line 2 is not what I want,i.e: I want the lines which the source port is 18812, rather than the dst port .
Any body knows how to deal with this? Thanks very much!

Edit: I tried regular expression, but "\d","+","\s" seems not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One small improvement to the solution in your comment to fedmich. Probably not needed for port 18812 since the max number of digits is 5, and you've used all of them. But if you are looking for a 4 digit port (or smaller), you will want to make sure there is a space after the port number.

For example, if you were looking for source port 3099

```
netstat -ano -p tcp | findstr /R /C:"TCP[ ]*[0-9.]*:3099 "
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using regular expression on the first and last part?

```
".*STRING.*"
```

Try this out.

```
netstat -ano -p tcp | findstr  ".*:18812.*"
```

Comment: I found it myself:    netstat -ano -p tcp | findstr  /R /C:"TCP[ ]*[0-9.]*:18812"